# Adding layer id data attribute to leaflet marker

Tags: leaflet

leaflet stores popups and markers in different divs.
Is there any way to add lets say the layer ID as a data attribute to a marker / the corresponding popup to allow me to save this to url params so I can set a view when someone opens the map using an URL with the id of that marker?

I mean I need some way to add the data to the popup so I can copy the url to the clipboard to make this work.

Any advice?

Comment: Do you have a unique reference to this marker? You need something which has the same id after the page has reloaded.

Comment: Each marker has an (javascript) ID (_leaflet.id) but I'm not sure how to actually output these as data attributes.

Comment: No you can't use the leaflet id because it is generated on each page reload new and can be different.

Comment: @FalkeDesign so is there an actual way to get this to work? I'm pretty sure I've seen it somewhere but its kinda confusing.

Comment: From where do you get the information on which coordinates you place the markers / layers? From a Database? From there you need to get a unique key too. If the user creates the marker in this session you need to store it in a database or in the `localStorage` of the Browser and create a custom key by your self which can not be used twice. A very simple solution would be to add the marker coords to the url but then you can't store multiple layers

Comment: Its actually just hardcoded geoJSON data.

Comment: then simply add to each feature a hardcoded id. Or do you have some properties from which you can create a unique key? Please share your geojson